# Error : A and B must be floating-point scalars

Tags: matlab, debugging, integral

I am trying to integrate a function between two points but I can't do it as I get the following error:

```
Error using integral (line 85)
A and B must be floating-point scalars.

Error in integrantK_sup (line 6)
I=integral(F1,double(ALPHA*R_int_ind),double(ALPHA*R_ext_ind)); % équation (70), p.2834

Error in Script_A_MH_L (line 228)
    integ=integrantK_sup(ALPHA);
```

The code used is :

```
nb_pt_v=200;  pas_v=Ep_plaque/nb_pt_v;
nb_pt_h=200;  pas_h=3*R_ext_ind/nb_pt_h;
ik=1:nb_pt_h+1;
il=1:nb_pt_v+1;
r=  0    + (ik-1).*pas_h;        
z=  0    - (il-1).*pas_v;        [r,z]=meshgrid(r,z);
A=zeros(nb_pt_v+1,nb_pt_h+1);

pas_alpha=10;
nb_pas_al=1500;
for ALPHA=0.1:pas_alpha:nb_pas_al
    integ=integrantK_sup(ALPHA);
    A=integ.*pas_alpha+A;
end
```

The integration function `integratingK_sup` is defined as follows:

```
function integ=integrantK_sup(ALPHA)
% équation (74), p.2835
global   r z R_int_ind R_ext_ind Ep_plaque Ep_ind Airgap w mur sigma_plaque  
F1=@(x)x.*besselj(1,x);
I=integral(F1,double(ALPHA*R_int_ind),double(ALPHA*R_ext_ind)); % équation (70), p.2834
Alpha_1=sqrt(ALPHA^2+1j*w*mur*sigma_plaque);

aa=I.*besselj(1,ALPHA.*r).*(exp(-ALPHA*Airgap)-exp(-ALPHA*(Airgap+Ep_ind)));
bb=(ALPHA*Alpha_1*exp(2*Alpha_1*Ep_plaque).*exp(Alpha_1.*z));
cc=ALPHA*Alpha_1.*exp(-Alpha_1.*z);
dd=((ALPHA-Alpha_1)*Alpha_1+Alpha_1*(ALPHA+Alpha_1)*exp(2*Alpha_1*Ep_plaque));

integ=((1/(ALPHA^3)).*aa).*((bb+cc)/dd);

end
```

To execute, you must first initialise the parameters:

```
Ep_plaque = 5e-3;
R_plaque = 20e-2;    
R_int_ind   = 5e-2;
R_ext_ind   = 15e-2;
Ep_ind      = 2e-3;
Airgap      = 2e-3;     
R_air = 5*R_plaque;
H_air = 100*Ep_plaque;
mu0=4*pi*1e-7;          %% Perméabilité magnétique du vide 
nu0=1/mu0;              %% Réluctivité magnétique du vide
mur=1e5;                %% Perméabilité magnétique relative 
nur=1.0/mur;            %% Perméabilité magnétique du circuit magnétique
Js=5e6;                 %% Densité de courant source
Is = Js *((R_ext_ind-R_int_ind)*Ep_ind); %% courant source 
ADirichlet=0;           %% Valeurs Dirichlet du potentiel vecteur magnétique 
sigma_plaque=1e6;       %% Conductivité électrique du circuit magnétique
fr=50000;               %% Fréquence de travail
w = 2*pi*fr ;           %% Pulsation
```

The problem is in the integration of the function `F1` between the two points `ALPHA * R_int_ind` and `ALPHA * R_ext_ind`.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint at the integral function to pause the script, what are the contents of ALPHA, R_int_ind, and R_ext_ind?

Comment: @FragileX `ALPHA = 0.1000`, `R_int_ind = 0.0500` and `R_ext_ind = 0.1500`.

Comment: Very odd. What’s the output of the calls to `double()` at that same breakpoint?

Comment: @FragileX do you want the result of the double function applied to the 3 variables ALPHA, R_int_ind, and R_ext_ind? If so, I get the same values quoted in my first answer.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering if the built-in `double()` got redefined, since I don’t see anything else wrong on the face of it.

Comment: @FragileX I found something a bit strange, originally I had set the breakpoint at the execution of the `integrantK_sup` function. I have now tried a breakpoint at `I=integral(F1,double(ALPHA*R_int_ind),double(ALPHA*R_ext_ind)); % equation (70), p.2834 `. I found `ALPHA = 0.1000` and to my surprise, `R_int_ind = [ ]` and `R_ext_ind = [ ]`. I'm beginning to doubt that this is due to the definition of the variables as global variables.

Comment: I see. Your initialized constants also need to be made`global` so that they can be seen inside `integrantK_sup`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our conversation in the comments, I was able to reproduce the error you saw by not making `R_int_ind` and `R_ext_ind` global at their point of initialization.  Here's a simplified version of your code with this error fixed:

```
% Script_A_MH_L
global R_int_ind R_ext_ind % <-- Global declaration added here.
R_int_ind   = 5e-2;
R_ext_ind   = 15e-2;

pas_alpha=10;
nb_pas_al=1500;
I=[];
for ALPHA=0.1:pas_alpha:nb_pas_al;
    I(end+1)=integrantK_sup(ALPHA);
end
```

```
% integrantK_sup
function I = integrantK_sup(ALPHA)
global R_int_ind R_ext_ind
F1=@(x)x.*besselj(1,x);
I=integral(F1,double(ALPHA*R_int_ind),double(ALPHA*R_ext_ind)); % équation (70), p.2834
end
```

Global variables are notorious for introducing confusion.  You might be better served by packaging your constants up in a struct and passing them to the functions that need them:

```
% Script_A_MH_L
constants.R_int_ind = 5e-2;
constants.R_ext_ind = 15e-2;

pas_alpha=10;
nb_pas_al=1500;
I=[];
for ALPHA=0.1:pas_alpha:nb_pas_al;
    I(end+1)=integrantK_sup(ALPHA,constants);
end
```

```
% integrantK_sup
function I = integrantK_sup(ALPHA,constants)
F1=@(x)x.*besselj(1,x);
I=integral(F1,double(ALPHA*constants.R_int_ind),double(ALPHA*constants.R_ext_ind)); % équation (70), p.2834
end
```